# Managing the Startup Applications

Tags: 12.04, startup-applications

I want to add **Avant Window Navigator** as a **startup application.** But what should I write on the **Command** and **Comment** box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

type code in terminal and write Avant Window Navigator instead of application name

```
dpkg -l | grep "application name"
```

for an example to learn chromium;

```
burak@stat:~$ dpkg -l | grep "chromium"
ii  chromium-browser                              32.0.1700.102-0ubuntu0.13.10.1~20140128.970.1 amd64        Chromium browser
ii  chromium-browser-l10n                         32.0.1700.102-0ubuntu0.13.10.1~20140128.970.1 all          chromium-browser language packages
ii  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra                  32.0.1700.102-0ubuntu0.13.10.1~20140128.970.1 amd64        Extra ffmpeg codecs for the Chromium Browser
ii  unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks                 0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1                   all          Chromium bookmarks scope for Unity
```

You can see the code which starts chromium in the second line "chromium-browser"

Have a nice day :)

Comment: 1. **dpkg** searches the installed application according to **command** name not the **Usual name**. Eg. You can't search like `dpkg -l | grep "Chromium Browser"` **2** You can't use **dpkg** with out **sudo** or **root** permission.  Although I appreciate you for your help, but please consider the valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

In **command** you've to write **avant-window-navigator** and in **comment** you can write any thing as you wish. for example **AWN - MacOS X for Gnome**. And in **name** also you can write any thing like **Avant Window Navigator**.

That's it. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Type sudo apt-get install avant-window-navigator (in case you have not installed it)
2. In order to know, which command to enter in command field: type synaptic in terminal (to open the synaptic manager). Type avant-window-navigator in search box. If you have installed it, it will be highlighted. Right-click it to open its properties, then in installed files tab you will see the files installed. If you have "/usr/bin/avant-window-navigator" in it, then thats your command to type in command field.
3. In startup applications preferences window, click add and type Avant Window Navigator in name field, type avant-window-navigator in command field and (optional) finally add your comment in comment field.
4. Click add to complete the startup application addition process.

Comment: Welcome to **askubuntu.com**!! It is preferred to not post duplicate answers. I don't see any difference in your answer. **OP** already knows how to add **Startup Applications**, but he doesn't know the command which should be added to execute **Avant Window Navigator**.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Check it out now.